# Does UIFontPickerViewController work in Catalyst?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mac-catalyst, uifontpickerviewcontroller

UIFontPickerViewController works fine in iOS but does not show up in Catalyst. No any errors in console. Just does not appear. UIFontPickerViewController is marked in Apple documentation as related to Mac Catalyst 13.0+, so, I believe, it must work.

Have anybody the same problem? Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured it out.
On iOS, UIFontPickerController is shown as a formsheet by default. But on Mac Catalyst it is kind of a popover, it needs to know its source view and source rect so it can properly position itself.
AND, unlike general popovers, UIFontPickerController on Mac Catalyst do not understand if its source is UIBarButtonItem. So, that’s it.